# How can i disable and enable 'mouseenter mouseleave' in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function and in this function i want to disable and enable mouse hover, i already have disable but i cant enable.

Here is my code thanks

```
$('.menuItem').hover(function(){

            var altura = $(this).height(); //altura da li
            altura = altura + 2; //altura da li mais 2 px

            var menuItemMostrar =  $(this).children('ul');  //
            menuItemMostrar.css('margin-top', -altura);     //  dar a margem e mostrar ul filha
            menuItemMostrar.show();                         //

        },function(){

            $(this).children('ul').hide(); // esconder Ul

            $('.collapseMenu').removeClass('ativo'); // remover Class
        });
```

```
function adicionarBotao(){

      $('.collapseBotao').parent('.menuItem').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
      $('.collapseBotao').remove();
      var botao = '<button class="collapseBotao">dasds</button>';

      var numeroDeBotoes = $('.collapseMenu').parent('.menuItem').children('.collapseBotao');

      console.log(numeroDeBotoes.length);
      if(numeroDeBotoes.length == 0){
        $('.collapseMenu').parent('.menuItem').prepend(botao);
      }

  }

  adicionarBotao();
  $(window).on('resize', adicionarBotao);
```

Comment: What are the handler functions for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`?

Comment: I ve already edit

Comment: Enable when and under what conditions? What is wrong with calling the `hover()` shown? Need a lot more detailed explanation of your issue and a [mcve] would help also

Comment: I want to enable before this function function adicionarBotao(){

Comment: So what is preventing you from doing that?